# Why a Arduino UNO R3 board can use in Windows 10 but can't be used in My Macbook Air(M1)?

Tags: arduino-uno, mac-os

In Windows 10, everything is well. But when I use it in my macbook, it even can't recognize the port. [image: this is the only three port, but these all not correct]

This is official description about driver.

[image]

Comment: First check if you have installed the driver.

Comment: It may make a difference if you're talking about a clone or an original. They don't all use the same transceiver. If you've been testing with anything besides the computer connected to the UNO, remove it.

Comment: I use a clone board, but the components is consistent with the original, use a Atmel Mega16U2 as usb-to-UART driver. According to official Web resource, this board don't need a software driver.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: I use Ventura 13.1.

Answer (score 1):

No driver necessary on MacOS which is essentially derived from UNIX/Linux.  It should be plug & play.
It looks like the Air is not recognizing the Uno.
Try opening a Terminal console and type `ls /dev/tty.*`
You should get a list of 'Serial Devices' connected, try the 'ls /dev/tty.* with the Uno plugged and unplugged, any difference should reveal the name of Uno port.  If no difference I would suspect the cable you are using to connect the Uno.  If you are able to identify the Uno port that same name should be selectable in the Arduino IDE when you open it.

Just realized Stack Exchange is not showning my answer correctly 'ls /dev/tty.' should have an asterisk after the 'dot'.

Comment: Before I asked, I have try check Terminal console output use the method which you say. Unfortunately there is no difference. Only have three COM port show in my description.  I don't think the cable is broken, because it's usable in Windows 10. I upload some code, and it performs well.

Comment: Okay, then the issue must lie with your macbook Air, I usually use a Windows 7/10 or Linux laptop with Arduino, but when I saw your post I pulled out my ancient Macbook pro, plugged in my Uno which works fine on Win7/10 & Ubuntu and voila, the serial device appears with ls /dev/tty.*  I looked up the specs on the Air M1, it has 2 Thunderbolt / USB-C 4 ports, my next step would be to look at the way they are configured if I was in your shoes.  If you have another device headset, camera etc try plugging that into the port and see what it does with ls /dev/tty.*

Comment: When i plug a STM32F411RE nucleo board, in terminal us ls /dev/tty.* I will see new port have the name of **tty.usbmodem23103**. I think it's time to buy a new one to test whether is My mac's problems.